# c++ "system" call doesn't doesn't return the proper exit code

Tags: c++, python, system-calls, exit-code

I have the following C++ code

```
...
int res = system("python myscript.py");
if(res != 0){
    cerr << "Exit code was:" << res << endl;
}
```

The python script file ends with

```
print "This will exit with code 0"
sys.exit(0)
```

If I run the python script directly, I get the proper exit code (0). However if I run it via the c++ app, res is -1, even though the line "This will exit with code 0" is properly printed.

Oddly enough, if I move the calls to the beginning of the execution of the C++ app, the exit code returned by the system call to python is correct.

What can cause it to become "wrong" along the way?

EDIT:

After adding some debug "cout" info around the issue... it disappeared. Looks like I have a Heisenbug.

Comment: From the documentation on my system: "If a child process cannot be created, or if the termination status for the command language interpreter cannot be obtained, system() shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error." Does `errno` tell you anything on your system too? (It's system-specific whether `errno` is useful here; actually, it's even system-specific whether the return value is meaningful at all.)

Comment: Please read this http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2346918

Comment: You're asking us to debug code we can't see. If I understand you correctly, the code above works by itself, right? (For example, if other code runs the script and then changes the working directory, that would perfectly explain your problem.)

Comment: What's the OS, if it's *nix, whats the shell that you are using?

Comment: the most likely thing to change during the process execution is the process state. i.e. current directory. use an absolute path to script (in order to not hardcode, good idea to create it from path to executable).

Comment: Yes the code there works by itself. The issue arrises when I make the system call at the end of my process. The main process is a whole application so I can't paste it here. Still, the python script is executed as expected. The only thing that is wrong here is the returned exit code. I'll look into errno and make another comment

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If the working directory changed, the python script would not work and hence the line "This will exit with code 0" would not be printed.

Comment: @Spundun It's a bash shell within Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the script is running?

Try

```
...
int res = system("/usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py");
if(res != 0){
    cerr << "Exit code was:" << res << endl;
}
```

Comment: The question already answers that: "even though the line "This will exit with code 0" is properly printed." The line will only be printed if the script actually runs.

Comment: OK my bad, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: @hvd: Well, the script was run at least once from somewhere, anyway. Since this code works by itself, it's entirely possible that the other code with which this code does not work is running the script, possibly even changing the working directory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ha, that's some nice creative thinking. I would like very much for that to be correct :)

Comment: No the call is not made from anywhere else. I'll add some output to make sure but runing grep over my source codes doesn't reveal any other python calls.